# Auto Submit Form, get XML returned on next page, then Auto Submit the new form with XML data

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, form-submit

HI all, I might be going about this all the wrong way, so any thoughts would be great.

Currently I have a form that takes data from the user input formats it into XML, puts that XML into a textarea and automatically submits it with document.insert.submit(); to this parse.php file.

I don't have any idea how the parse.php file handles data, but know it returns an XML string to me if I feed it some XML.

I am trying to get this XML data that is returned into a string or variable I can break apart and take certain parameters out of.

I have looked at the .ajax() jquery, but am not sure how to submit this form and get my data returned in a variable from it.

How can I get this XML that is being returned?

Thanks!

Comment: I cannot use JSON, it's not supported on the server. PHP 4.x.x.

Comment: XML is cumbersome. Try googling a bit, somebody has surely written a JSON serialization implementation in pure PHP.

Comment: I've used [this one](http://hotblocks.nl/js/inc.cls.json.php.txt) for a while, before I discovered json_encode and json_decode.

Comment: I've posted the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this script to your page:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var $form = $(document.insert);
        $form.submit(function(){
           $.ajax({
              type: $form.attr("method") || 'get',
              url: $form.attr("action"),
              data: $form.serialize(),
              dataType: 'text', //Disables xml autoparsing
              success: function(xml){
                 //Now you have server response in the 'xml' var
                 alert('Xml returned by server: ' + xml);
              }
           });
           return false; //Cancel normal submission
        });
    });
</script>
```

And then try to submit your form. You'll get the xml from the server.
Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Hi Edgar, I am getting the page with the XML to be submitted, but not the XML that is returned? My form action calls feedback.php that takes my textarea data and puts the vars into and XML string, that then gets submitted through my autosubmit form to parse.php. Parse.php is where the XML string I want to return is. Is there a way to return what is on parse.php?

Comment: Hi again, I have finally gotten a response... I didn't note this, but this is from one domain to another, and this AJAX request doesn't work this way from what I gather. So I am using the [Cross Domain AJAX](https://github.com/jamespadolsey/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax) script. I got the first response back as [object Object]. Now, I haven't a clue as to what that is doing or saying, but at least it's a response. Any other thoughts would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: If you have firebug for firefox, you could do a `console.log(response);` to obtain more information of the response. If you want to use alert, this will give you more information: `alert(JSON.stringify(response));`